# Split it into an array

Tags: c#, string

I have this string of proxy addresses, they are separated by an space, however x400 and x500 handles spaces into their addresses. What's the best approach to split it.

e.g.

```
smtp:john@a-mygot.com smtp:john@b-mygot.com smtp:john@c-mygot.com X400:C=us;A= ;P=mygot;O=Exchange;S=John;G=Gleen; SMTP:john@mygot.com
```

Expected result:

```
smtp:john@a-mygot.com
smtp:john@b-mygot.com
smtp:john@c-mygot.com
X400:C=us;A= ;P=mygot;O=Exchange;S=John;G=Gleen;
SMTP:john@mygot.com
```

thanks,

EDIT,

```
        string mylist = "smtp:john@a-mygot.com smtp:john@b-mygot.com smtp:john@c-mygot.com X400:C=us;A= ;P=mygot;O=Exchange;S=John;G=Gleen; SMTP:john@mygot.com X500:/o=Example/ou=USA/cn=Recipients of  /cn=juser smtp:myaddress";

        string[] results = Regex.Split(mylist, @" +(?=\w+:)");
        foreach (string part in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(part);
        }
```

Result

```
smtp:john@a-mygot.com
smtp:john@b-mygot.com
smtp:john@c-mygot.com
X400:C=us;A= ;P=mygot;O=Exchange;S=John;G=Gleen;
SMTP:john@mygot.com
X500:/o=Example/ou=USA/cn=Recipients of  /cn=juser
smtp:myaddress
```

Comment: Well you could split on SMTP, then add that back in, or it's time to have fun with regular expressions.

Comment: Get the substring between smtp and x400,x400 and the next smtp. 
Then split on the individual strings (in fact only one string.. the first substring).

Comment: OP - do you have control over the input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a Regex that should match the spaces before protocols.  Try plugging it into `Regex.Split` like so:

```
string[] results = Regex.Split(input, @" +(?=\w+:)");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = smtp.indexOf("X400") ;
string[] smtps = smtpString.SubString(0,index).Split(" ") ;
int secondIndex  = smtpString.indexOf("SMTP");
string xfour = smtpString.substring(index,secondIndex);
string lastString = smtpString.indexOf(secondIndex) ;
```

Should work, if the string format is that way.. and if I didn't screw up the indexes.. although you might want to check if the index isn't -1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static string[] SplitProxy(string text)
        {
            var list = new List<string>();
            var tokens = text.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
            var currentToken = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var token in tokens)
            {
                if (token.ToLower().Substring(0, 4) == "smtp")
                {
                    if (currentToken.Length > 0)
                    {
                        list.Add(currentToken.ToString());
                        currentToken.Clear();
                    }

                    list.Add(token);
                }
                else
                {
                    currentToken.Append(token);
                }
            }

            if (currentToken.Length > 0)
                        list.Add(currentToken.ToString());

            return list.ToArray();
        }
```

It splits the string by spaces into tokens then goes through them one by one. If the token starts with smtp it is added to the result array. If not, that token is concatted with the following tokens to create one entry than is added to the result array. Should work with anything that has spaces and doesn't start with smtp.

Answer (score -1):

I reckon the following line should do the work

```
var addrlist = variable.Split(new char[] { ' ' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: I don't think that will work because there's a space after A=.